# Dangers of hashing known plain text

Tags: rest, security

I have easily guessable internal identifiers (auto increasing numbers) and I'd like to give my clients access to resources based on these identifiers.

Of cause I cannot provide them with an URL like:

> https://example.com/order/13

because they could easily guess how to access order #14 from this URL.

I therefore thought about providing them with a salted hash of the identifier like:

> https://example.com/order/4643ef…

where

```
4643ef… = sha256(13 + 'supersecretsalt')
```

Is this a good approach from a security perspective?

Comment: Stick a database lookup inbetween using a table with the true value and say a guid or highly random string?

Comment: I thought about this, too. Actually it seams a lot better since I would have to cache the hashes anyway since otherwise I would need to calculate the hash for every object on every access

Comment: What's the problem, really, with having the identifier in the URI in plaintext? Whether it's easy to guess or not your server should be explicitly verifying that the user accessing the resource is authorised to access it. Easily guessable URIs is not a security problem on its own.

Comment: @sisyphus While I agree in general with you here, I can easily imagine situations in which it might be preferable to keep for instance an orderId secret. The overhead of using e.g. a GUID to abstract away the real ID would likely not be large, and it might provide an extra layer of security.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your should not be granting access to any resource simply based on a uri. In other words, user A should not be able to access a resource that belongs to user B *even if he knows the relevant uri*. To mitigate this, you should add some form of authentication and authorization before allowing access to any (confidential?) resources.

That said, if you'd still like to obfuscate the uri, you can probably use a [GUID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Standards) for this instead of generating any kind of hash. Instead, fore each order ID, simply store a GUID together with it, and then look that ID up whenever the GUID is used in an url.

---

***Sidenote:*** If you do want to let your customers look up some order-details based simply on a url (i.e. without requiring identification), you might at least make the availability of the resource temporary. You can do this by storing e.g. a *valid until*-date together with the GUID.

Now user A will be able to see info relating to his resource via a url with a guid, but perhaps only for e.g. 3 days. Other users would also be able to access it, but it would be less likely to happen, both because it would be hard to guess the GUID, and because they would only have a 3 day window to do so.

If user A needs to access his resource again later, perhaps you could provide a way to extend the *validity* of the GUID, or alternatively just provide a new GUID that points to the same resource, but with a different validity date.

Obviously you'll need to thing through whether or not this is realistic / acceptable for your particular situation and security needs.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However could you please elaborate why the URI should not count as secret? It's as guessable / unguessable as any other form of authentication. Is this a special case because GET requests might get logged where as Authentication headers are less likely to be?

Comment: @ooxi If you mean the uri-format itself, I'd assume a regularly increasing number (e.g. an order ID) would be significantly easier to guess than a more complex GUID. As to why I would not consider it a safe secret, there are several reasons: A GET-request must be sent across the network in plaintext, while a password in a Post may be encrypted; also, there is the issue of logging in various locations (server, client, browser, ..?), and possibly even automatic discovery and indexing by search-engines. Proper authentication and / or time limited access may at least partly mitigate this.